# "use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Plugin'" what's the meaning of the quoted statement?

Tags: perl

Could someone please lead me to an informative page, where i can read about how this syntax works and what it actually does?
In Instance, what's the difference between...
`use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Plugin';`
and
`use Mojo::Base;` ?

I don't really understand the quoted `'Foo::Bar'` part, in the example above, the `'Mojolicious::Plugin'` part.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See the [Mojo::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Base) documentation

Comment: thanks for your feedback, but unfortunately this won't help me. the question is not specific related to MOJO, it's just about the syntax "FOO::BAR 'baz'". i know what FOO::BAR is for, but 'baz'?

Comment: See documentation for [use Module LIST](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Mojo::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Base) documentation. 
I have not used this package myself, but it seems like `use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Plugin'` is a shortcut for the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature ':5.10';
use mro;
use IO::Handle ();
require Mojolicious::Plugin;
push @ISA, 'Mojolicious::Plugin';
sub has { Mojo::Base::attr(__PACKAGE__, @_) }
```

Comment: thanks, so in vanilla perl, there is never a " 'baz' " after the " use FOO::BAR " ?

Comment: Yes it can be, for example `use List::Util 'max'` to import the `max` subroutine from `List::Util`

Answer (score 3):

`use Module::Name 'foo', 'bar'` will (as a compile time statement) load the `Module::Name` module, and then call its `import` method passing the list `'foo', 'bar'`. See the documentation for [use](https://perldoc.pl/functions/use) and [import](https://perldoc.pl/functions/import). A module can define its import method to do anything it wants, but [Exporter](https://perldoc.pl/Exporter) is a common way to get an import method that exports functions by name.

For Mojo::Base specifically, its import method when passed a class name will set up the current package to be a subclass of the passed class name. It also does a lot of other setup by default as documented.